How to keep a local variable from being disposed
I'm trying to understand Swift better through this example. If in the following code the variable snapshotter is declared as a class variable the function startSnapshot does it's intended purpose. But as soon as the variable snapshotter is moved to a local variable the code stops working as snapshotter.onStyleLoaded.observeNext is never triggered.
I feel as if there should be a way to wait at the end of startSnapshot until all tasks have been finished, but I can't figure out how the waiting should be done.

import UIKit
import MapboxMaps

final class SnapshotterCoreGraphicsExample: UIViewController, NonMapViewExampleProtocol {
  private var snapshotView: UIImageView!
  private var cancelables = Set<AnyCancelable>()
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Add the `UIImageView` that will eventually render the snapshot.
    snapshotView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    snapshotView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(snapshotView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      snapshotView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
      snapshotView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
    ])
    
    startSnapshot()
  }
   
  private func startSnapshot() {
    // Configure the snapshot options, such as the size, scale and style to be used.
    // Here we use a scale (pixelRatio) that is different than the display's
    // scale (UIScreen.main.scale)
    let options = MapSnapshotOptions(size: CGSize(width: view.bounds.size.width, height: view.bounds.height), pixelRatio: 4)
    
    var snapshotter = Snapshotter(options: options)
    snapshotter.styleURI = .dark
    snapshotter.setCamera(to: CameraOptions(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.180885866921386, longitude: 16.26129435178828), zoom: 4))
    
    snapshotter.onStyleLoaded.observeNext { [weak self] _ in
      // Begin the snapshot after the style is loaded into the `Snapshotter`.
      // The `SnapshotOverlay` object contains references to the current
      // graphics context being used by the Snapshotter and provides closures to
      // perform coordinate conversion between map and screen coordinates.
      snapshotter.start { ( overlayHandler ) in
        let context = overlayHandler.context
        
        // Convert the map coordinates for Berlin and Kraków to points,
        // in order to correctly position the Core Graphics drawing code.
        let berlin = overlayHandler.pointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.53, longitude: 13.38))
        let krakow = overlayHandler.pointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.06, longitude: 19.92))
        
        // Draw a yellow line between Berlin and Kraków.
        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.yellow.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(6.0)
        context.setLineCap(.round)
        context.move(to: berlin)
        context.addLine(to: krakow)
        context.strokePath()
      } completion: { [weak self] result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let image):
          self?.snapshotView.image = image
        case .failure(let error):
          print("Error generating snapshot: \(error)")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


I have tried using a DispatchGroup, Semaphore and DispatchQueue but I seem to be missing something as what I achieve is either blocking the UI thread or nothing happens.
What is the correct way to handle this situation so that snapshotter can remain a local variable?

How about don't declare snapshotter as a local var? What's wrong with declaring it outside of the startSnapshot method?

Because I know how to solve this problem in other languages and I'm trying to understand swift better.

You are looking for the new Swift async/await concurrency. APIs need to support it, however. The api you are dealing with is using a closure. You can use withCheckedContinuation to adapt closure based APIs to async/await

I don't have Mapbox to try this out, but a shot in the dark - try capturing snapshotter in one of the closures. Like snapshotter.start { [snapshotter] (overlayHandler) in or completion: { [weak self, snapshotter] result in. This may or may not cause a retain cycle, depending on how Mapbox is implemented.

The issue lies in creating a subscription without storing it. In your case, the observeNext method returns an AnyCancelable object, which you need to store in your cancelables variable. This ensures that your subscription remains active. Therefore, you just need to do this:
snapshotter.onStyleLoaded.observeNext { ... }.store(in: &cancelables)

After storing the subscription observeNext will be called.

You are correct that snapshotter.onStyleLoaded.observeNextis called but the variable snapshotteris destroyed during the execution of the handler...

I suppose the subscription is being cancelled automatically after observeNext completion, and the snapshotter lost its strong reference. I'm not familiar with the MapboxMaps library; I can only examine their source on GitHub. Based on what I've seen, I believe they might be using the snapshotter in a different way. You can find an example here https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-ios/blob/main/Apps/Examples/Examples/All%20Examples/SnapshotterExample.swift
They create variable in class and use it in functions:
var snapshotter: Snaphotter?
inside function snapshotter  = Snaphotter()

There is only one way in swift to keep object alive, it is to retain a strong reference to it. Typically, this is achieved through a variable within a class, providing a straightforward approach. Another way is through closures, but this requires a thorough understanding of the library to avoid inadvertently creating reference cycles with memory leaks.

The example code is from their github, with some minor modifications for simplicity sake. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-ios/blob/main/Apps/Examples/Examples/All%20Examples/SpinningGlobeExample.swift

withCheckedContinuation as hinted by Paulw11 seems to be currently the only possible solution that is getting close to what I'm asking

You are using observeNext, and the docs say:

Adds an observer closure that will be triggered only once.
…
If it is canceled or deinited the subscription will be cancelled immediately.
Analogous to prefix(1).sink in Combine.

So, you need to save that AnyCancelable in a property or else it will be immediately deinited (and canceled). (FWIW, the code already has a property for this purpose, but it never uses it.)
And the whole purpose of this method is to watch for some change over time, so that only makes sense if the Snapshotter persists over time, too, which is why it also should be defined as a property as well.
But, in your example, you are setting the style up front, and never changing it. So, why you would bother with onStyleLoaded.observeNext at all? You can just use snapshotter directly. If you do that, you can use local variables:
private func startSnapshot() {
    let snapshotter = Snapshotter(
        options: MapSnapshotOptions(size: snapshotView.bounds.size, pixelRatio: 4)
    )

    snapshotter.styleURI = .dark
    snapshotter.setCamera(to: CameraOptions(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.180885866921386, longitude: 16.26129435178828), zoom: 4))

    snapshotter.start { overlayHandler in
        …
    } completion: { [weak self] result in
        …
    }
}

No Snapshotter or Set<AnyCancelable> properties are needed at all.

For your reference, here is the MRE:
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var snapshotView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configure()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        startSnapshot()
    }
}

private extension ViewController {
    func configure() {
        snapshotView = UIImageView()
        snapshotView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(snapshotView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            snapshotView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            snapshotView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            snapshotView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            snapshotView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }

    private func startSnapshot() {
        // Configure the snapshot options, such as the size, scale and style to be used.
        // Here we use a scale (pixelRatio) that is different than the display's
        // scale (UIScreen.main.scale)
        let snapshotter = Snapshotter(
            options: MapSnapshotOptions(size: snapshotView.bounds.size, pixelRatio: 4)
        )

        snapshotter.styleURI = .dark
        snapshotter.setCamera(to: CameraOptions(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.180885866921386, longitude: 16.26129435178828), zoom: 4))

        snapshotter.start { overlayHandler in
            let context = overlayHandler.context

            // Convert the map coordinates for Berlin and Kraków to points,
            // in order to correctly position the Core Graphics drawing code.
            let berlin = overlayHandler.pointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.53, longitude: 13.38))
            let krakow = overlayHandler.pointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.06, longitude: 19.92))

            // Draw a yellow line between Berlin and Kraków.
            context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.yellow.cgColor)
            context.setLineWidth(6)
            context.setLineCap(.round)
            context.move(to: berlin)
            context.addLine(to: krakow)
            context.strokePath()
        } completion: { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let image):
                self?.snapshotView.image = image
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error generating snapshot: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}

(Unrelated to the question at hand, but I would refrain from creating the snapshot in viewDidLoad because the frames have not yet been established.)

So, let’s step back. What is the purpose of onStyleLoaded?
The whole point is that if you change the style of the Snapshotter in the future, the snapshot observer will automatically re-render. But that obviously only makes sense if the Snapshotter was a property, not a local variable.
Also, often you would use observe, not observeNext. And, you now would take advantage of the previously-unused Set<AnyCancelable>.
Consider, this example where I added a button to toggle between light and dark mode:
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var snapshotView: UIImageView!
    private var cancelables = Set<AnyCancelable>()
    private lazy var snapshotter = Snapshotter(
        options: MapSnapshotOptions(size: snapshotView.bounds.size, pixelRatio: 4)
    )

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configure()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        cancelables.removeAll()
        startSnapshot()
    }
}

private extension ViewController {
    func configure() {
        snapshotView = UIImageView()
        snapshotView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(snapshotView)

        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Toggle", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapToggle(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            snapshotView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            snapshotView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            snapshotView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            snapshotView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),

            button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
        ])
    }

    @objc func didTapToggle(_ sender: Any) {
        let isDark = snapshotter.styleURI == .dark
        snapshotter.styleURI = isDark ? .light : .dark
    }

    private func startSnapshot() {
        // Configure the snapshot options, such as the size, scale and style to be used.
        // Here we use a scale (pixelRatio) that is different than the display's
        // scale (UIScreen.main.scale)
        snapshotter.styleURI = .dark
        snapshotter.setCamera(to: CameraOptions(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.180885866921386, longitude: 16.26129435178828), zoom: 4))

        snapshotter.onStyleLoaded.observe { [snapshotter] _ in

            // Begin the snapshot after the style is loaded into the `Snapshotter`.
            // The `SnapshotOverlay` object contains references to the current
            // graphics context being used by the Snapshotter and provides closures to
            // perform coordinate conversion between map and screen coordinates.

            let isDark = snapshotter.styleURI == .dark

            snapshotter.start { overlayHandler in
                let context = overlayHandler.context

                // Convert the map coordinates for Berlin and Kraków to points,
                // in order to correctly position the Core Graphics drawing code.
                let berlin = overlayHandler.pointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 52.53, longitude: 13.38))
                let krakow = overlayHandler.pointForCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.06, longitude: 19.92))

                // Draw a yellow line between Berlin and Kraków.
                let color: UIColor = isDark ? .yellow : .brown
                context.setStrokeColor(color.cgColor)
                context.setLineWidth(6)
                context.setLineCap(.round)
                context.move(to: berlin)
                context.addLine(to: krakow)
                context.strokePath()
            } completion: { [weak self] result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let image):
                    self?.snapshotView.image = image
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error generating snapshot: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        .store(in: &cancelables)
    }
}

Note, I just toggle between light and dark mode, and the snapshot is automatically re-rendered for me.
But, getting back to the question at hand, they have clearly modeled their AnyCancelable after Combine’s AnyCancellable, and if you want to observe values over time, you would just follow that same pattern. Just use properties if you want to observe changes to the style. And make sure to add store(in:).

Now, you have contemplated a Swift concurrency rendition wrapping this in withCheckedContinuation. That would be fine if you were trying to handle observeNext only. But you probably would want to handle observe, too, which would probably call for some AsyncSequence or AsyncStream. And once you do that, observeNext might be considered a special use-case of observe (where you only get the first value).
I played around with this a bit, and it got a bit hairy. You can pursue this if you really want, but given that observeNext is likely not needed at all, I decided to not spend any more time playing around with it.

Completely unrelated, but I find their name of their AnyCancelable type to be a very curious design choice. I appreciate what they were trying to do (to offer Combine-like behaviors in pre iOS 13), but to name a type to something that just looks like a misspelling of Combine’s AnyCancellable type is questionable. If I were on their design team, I would have lobbied for something like MapBox.AnyCancellable. Completely unrelated to the discussion at hand, but just sayin’…

The thing is that I need to do multiple snapshots in parallel i.e. imagine a snapshot is being taken at button press. While the snapshot process is pretty quick it's still slow enough so that if clicked fast enough the previous snapshot process would in progress and would be cancelled. As a quick workaround I chucked the snapshotter instance into a dictionary for the duration of the process and it works well enough. I managed to get withCheckedContinuation working but it has some rendering artefacts. The goal of this question was to understand how to properly solve this issue with swift.
